# Nested Template Class

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to obtain a **nested template class**.
The compiler gives me the following error:

> error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template class MyClass’
>   note:   expected a class template, got ‘SpecificType {aka TemplateClass< Type1, Typ2, Type3 >}

This is my code

```
/* ...class definition... */
template < template < typename T1,typename T2,typename T3 > typename T>
class MyClass{ 
    // is there a way to have these types available here
    // passing one single specialized type in the main?
    T1 member1;
    T2 member2;
    T3 member3;
    T<T1, T2, T3> member4;
};

/*  ...in my main... */
using SpecificType =  TemplateClass< Type1, Type2, Type3 >;
SpecificType test_object; //until here compiles
MyClass< SpecificType > myclass;
```

I have already tried to define a **SpecificType** object, and until that point my code compiles and works.

Comment: `SpecificType` is not a tempalte anymore (you alreay provided the parameters to `TemplateClass`). `MyClass<TemplateClass>` should be fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define `MyClass` to accept a template as parameter and not a type. As this you simply should pass the template e.g. `TemplateClass` itself.

So your definition says: I want to have a template which itself has three template parameters. So you must pass a template and not a instance of a template.

```
/* ...class definition... */
template < template < typename T1,typename T2,typename T3 > typename T>
class MyClass{ /*...*/};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class TemplateClass {};

/*  ...in my main... */
int main()
{
    MyClass< TemplateClass > myclass;
}
```

After passing the template to your class, inside the class you can use the template to instantiate it like:

```
template < template < typename T1,typename T2,typename T3 > typename T>
class MyClass
{
    T<int, float, char> obj;
};
```

After getting your comment, you want a different thing! You want to pass a type, here you want the instance of a template. So simply do the following:

```
/* ...class definition... */
template < typename T>
class MyClass
{ 
    T obj;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> 
class TemplateClass {}; 

int main()
{   
    MyClass< TemplateClass< int, float, char> > myclass;
}
```

And now to get the second request from OP :-)

It is possible to pass a type ( e.g. here we see the instantiated template ) and get out the types from the template parameters. Look here:

```
template < typename T>
class MyClass;

template < template < typename ,typename ,typename  > typename T, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class MyClass< T<T1,T2,T3> >
{
    T1 var1; // here you can use the types... 
    T2 var2;

    T<T1,T2,T3> obj;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
class TemplateClass {};

int main()
{
    MyClass< TemplateClass< int, float, char> > myclass;
}
```

Comment: nitpicking: not sure about the term "instance of a template". Strictly speaking there are no instances of templates (instance in the sense of object ... I know what you mean, but still it can be misunderstood). suggestion: replace with "concrete type (resulting from instantiating a template)" (more clear what meaning of "instantiating" is meant)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right in the first part. In the second part, i.e. the instantiation, it looks like I should be aware of the specific type. Imagine that **MyClass** is in my library, and I want to specify the types outside the library. How can I pass them?

Comment: @BartoloDellaCorte simply make `MyClass` accept a type as tempalte parameter (instead of requiring a template)

Comment: @BartoloDellaCorte: You should simply accept a type and not a template... added this in my answer.

Comment: @Klaus I was trying to have some sort of 'visibility', inside `MyClass`, of the three typename used in `TemplateClass`, to get some static members values. Probably I should change design

Comment: @tobi303: from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template: `A class template by itself is not a type, or an object, or any other entity. No code is generated from a source file that contains only template definitions. In order for any code to appear, a template must be instantiated`

Comment: @Klaus I completely agree with the text you quote, but I dont understand the relevance for my original "complaint". I never read "instance of a template" and imho that term is confusing. In general classes are not called instances, but the objects are called instances, ie instantiations of classes are called instances

Comment: @tobi303: Maybe a misunderstanding? If I instantiate a template the result is not a template instance?

Comment: from my original comment: "Strictly speaking there are no instances of templates (**instance in the sense of object ... I know what you mean, but still it can be misunderstood**). " What you wrote is strictly speaking not wrong, I just find it confusing to extend the term "instance" to a "class that is the result of instantiating a template"

Comment: @tobi303: you are right. There is instance of a class and of a template... maybe I look for better wording... first I add my answer with content for getting type of template parms...

Comment: I've updated my question to better reflect my needs. A fast solution is to pass 4 typenames <T1, T2, T3, T>. I was looking for something more elegant to be used at higher level. Anyway guys, thanks for the answers, and for the template-instantiation discussion

Comment: @BartoloDellaCorte: see my last extension. Here you see how to get the parameters of the template...

Comment: @BartoloDellaCorte you shouldnt change the question too much when there are already answers, maybe rather ask a new question. SO isnt really for discussions. Anyhow, just pass `TemplateClass` as parameter to `MyClass` not `SpecificType` (which is not a template, but a specific type)